# FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly (The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found)

Tags: c#, .net, reference, .net-assembly

I have a problem with a version mismatch and no idea to solve it.

## Situation

### initial situation

- *Integration.DataExchange.Processing.Implementation* is build by buildserver --> 7.0.85.27765
- *Integration.DataExchange.TestTools* and *Integration.DataExchange.Processing.Test* is build manually --> 7.0.85.1420
- *Integration.Infrastructure.Serialization.Test* uses them and throws the **exception**

---

## Log

### Error message from test

```
Test method Integration.Infrastructure.Serialization.ProcessInfoSerializerTests.SerializeAndDeserializeShouldBehaveResultInfoWithSameValues threw exception: 
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Integration.DataExchange.Processing.Implementation, Version=7.0.85.1420, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f15342ffe5641632' 
or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

### corresponding fusion log

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (25.02.2014 @ 09:49:58) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80131040. No description available.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\QTAgent.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Integration.DataExchange.Processing.Implementation, Version=7.0.85.1420, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f15342ffe5641632
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///d:/sources/Core/Bin/Debug
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = QTAgent.exe
Calling assembly : Integration.Infrastructure.Serialization.Test, Version=1.0.453.2209, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp913E.tmp
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Integration.DataExchange.Processing.Implementation, Version=7.0.85.1420, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f15342ffe5641632
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///d:/sources/Core/Bin/Debug/Integration.DataExchange.Processing.Implementation.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: d:\sources\Core\Bin\Debug\Integration.DataExchange.Processing.Implementation.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: Integration.DataExchange.Processing.Implementation, Version=7.0.85.27765, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f15342ffe5641632
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Revision Number
ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.
ERR: Run-from-source setup phase failed with hr = 0x80131040.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

---

## Solution

### what I think

*Integration.Infrastructure.Serialization.Test* uses a function from *Integration.DataExchange.TestTools* version 7.0.85.1420. The TestTools wants to load *Integration.DataExchange.Processing.Implementation* with version 1420 too. But only 27765 is found.

### what I don't understand

in every reference is a non-specific version. So I thought the version is irrelevant

---

## CS-Project files

### Integration.DataExchange.TestTools.csproj

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\Processing\Interface\Integration.DataExchange.Processing.Interface.csproj">
  <Project>{A67C3F93-F3CA-4746-9E5F-36645CD1A206}</Project>
  <Name>Integration.DataExchange.Processing.Interface</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

### Integration.DataExchange.Processing.Test.csproj

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\Implementation\Integration.DataExchange.Processing.Implementation.csproj">
  <Project>{61BF5881-C4B1-47E0-9B68-C9517FE3302E}</Project>
  <Name>Integration.DataExchange.Processing.Implementation</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

### Integration.Infrastructure.Serialization.Test.csproj

```
<Reference Include="Integration.DataExchange.Processing.Implementation">
        <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    </Reference>
<Reference Include="Integration.DataExchange.Processing.Interface">
        <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    </Reference>
<Reference Include="Integration.DataExchange.Processing.Test">
  <HintPath>$(SolutionDir)Lib\Debug\DataExchange.Test\Integration.DataExchange.Processing.Test.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Integration.DataExchange.TestTools">
  <HintPath>$(SolutionDir)Lib\Debug\DataExchange.Test\Integration.DataExchange.TestTools.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also set the SpecificVersion=false in all other .csproj Files - most likely it is the "Integration.DataExchange.Processing.Test.csproj"

EDIT:
because the error message states: "the assembly XXX or one of its dependencies could not be loaded"

Comment: but this is a projectreference and I think with this type it is not possible to set the specificversion?!? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915712/how-to-set-specific-version-property-for-project-references-in-visual-studio

Comment: @masterchris_99 it seems with the mixture of project reference and ordinary reference you managed to get in a real painful situation. I did just check a .net assembly with a project reference and this confirms your situation. If you have a project reference, the version number is also considered. Are the version numbers always the same? If so you could use binding redirects: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: No the versions from the automatically builded assembly are updated every night.

Comment: @masterchris_99 I think then you can only change your project references to ordinary references and set SpecificVersion=false